# Color and depth stream don't work anymore

Tags: kinect

I used until yesterday afternoon a Kinect for XBOX 360 on my computer, a MacBook Pro 15" Late 2011, whose specifications are available [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp644). I use Windows 7 (natively installed, without using virtual machines). The version of the SDK I had installed was 1.0.

All of a sudden, from today the Kinect no longer worked. Initially I thought it was some error in my code, but I noticed that the program remained stuck at the beginning, when I called the method `KinectSensor.Start()`.

I started looking for information on the internet. I read about a solution obtained by reinstalling the drivers. It did not work, and then I tried to install version 1.6 of the SDK. Unfortunately, even that did not work.

I've seen at this stage, there might be compatibility issues with certain USB host controllers, such as the Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB host controller. In my case, however, there should be no problems (because there were not ever been up to yesterday):

[image: The Windows device manager shows that the USB controllers should not cause problems]

To check if the problem was really due to the sensor, and not to my application, I run one of the test applications provided with the SDK, called *Kinect Explorer*. However, I encountered the same problem with this test application. After waiting about one minute, when the Kinect Explorer starts I cannot see neither the color stream, nor the depth stream, nor information about skeleton. The only thing I can do is move the Kinect up and down, changing the angle of the neck. Even the microphone array seems to work properly.

[image: The Kinect Explorer not works properly]

I read two interesting posts about this kind of problem: [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/73426beb-8ff2-43f5-b3c7-2fe4679263fd/) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/openni-dev/K2OK9-Fj5CI), which have not been answered.

In the first of these two links, the user who reports the problem says that the hardware has been compromised. I thought the same thing myself until I started again Kinect Explore, initially with the sensor unplugged. Once started this program, I plug-in the cable, and I noticed that Kinect Explorer has marked the Kinect sensor as **Connected**. After a short initialization phase, I again see the color stream, while the depth stream showed an image of uniform color (green-gray):

[image: The sensor seems work, but this only lasts a few seconds]

This situation lasted a few seconds, after which the image is locked and the question came up. Also, sometimes the FPS value drops from 30 to 29.

I am able to reproduce this latter situation only after keeping the Kinect unplugged for a while (10 minutes are sufficient).

How can I solve this strange and terrible problem? Is it possible to restore the Kinect sensor, and make it works again? Or do I have to conclude that the sensor is irretrievably broken?

Comment: Hardware problem diagnostics are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an hardware problem... Is it possible it depends on some software settings?

Comment: Diagnosing software problems is not on-topic either, unless it's your software (you wrote it), which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: did you install new kinect sdk..(version)?? then you will need to update reference

Comment: The problem occurs regardless of the SDK version. I tried with the both the 1.6 and the 1.0, with the same result

Comment: seems to me as HW error (IR camera, IR LASER or diffraction fresnel optics for IR LASER) most likely the LASER is overheating and electronics turn it off ... after 10 mins its cooled down again. also could be problem with old electrolyte capacitors in constant current circuit for IR LASER or just some dirt in the way of the LASER beam which reflects back and overheats something. If it is in the IR camera then you are screwed.

Comment: Could it be solved changing some fans?